# SharePoint Online MIP (Microsoft Information Protection) encrypted document in content search

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to find a way that encrypted document (using MIP)  and its content, will it get indexed for content search? I found some article saying *"encrypted and protected doc, if such documents get uploaded in SharePoint. SharePoint online will not be able to access document contents within the file so search for file content is not possible"*
But we want to search the content and display in search result, only while opening the document user can see the protection applied. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Emily's reply help you?

Comment: Yes, Emily's reply was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security, there is no option to show encrypted document in the content search.